# Input values from exported class are not recognized, resulting in an error rendering them as Undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am on Ionic Framework 6.13.1, and I have 2 services with the same structure of code. I have an `appointment.service.ts` and a `registration.service.ts`. Each of these services refers to a separate Typescript file containing only an exported class for storing values, with the class for `registration.service.ts` being in `Registration.ts` and the one for `appointment.service.ts` being in `Appointment.ts`. Here is the code for each of the aforementioned files:

`appointment.service.ts`:

> ```
> import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
> import { Appointment } from '../shared/Appointment';
> import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireObject } from '@angular/fire/database';
>
> @Injectable({
>   providedIn: 'root'
> })
> export class AppointmentService {
>   bookingListRef: AngularFireList<any>;
>   bookingRef: AngularFireObject<any>;
>
>   constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }
>
>   // Create
>   createBooking(apt: Appointment) {
>     return this.bookingListRef.push({
>       name: apt.name,
>       email: apt.email,
>       mobile: apt.mobile,
>       car: apt.car,
>       image1: apt.image1,
>       minPrice: apt.minPrice,
>       maxPrice: apt.maxPrice,
>       steps: apt.steps
>     })
>   }
>
>   // Get Single
>   getBooking(id: string) {
>     this.bookingRef = this.db.object('/appointment/' + id);
>     return this.bookingRef;
>   }
>
>   // Get List
>   getBookingList() {
>     this.bookingListRef = this.db.list('/appointment');
>     return this.bookingListRef;
>   }
>
>   // Update
>   updateBooking(id, apt: Appointment) {
>     return this.bookingRef.update({
>       name: apt.name,
>       email: apt.email,
>       mobile: apt.mobile,
>       car: apt.car,
>       image1: apt.image1,
>       minPrice: apt.minPrice,
>       maxPrice: apt.maxPrice,
>       steps: apt.steps
>     })
>   }
>
>   // Delete
>   deleteBooking(id: string) {
>     this.bookingRef = this.db.object('/appointment/' + id);
>     this.bookingRef.remove();
>   }
> }
> ```

`Appointment.ts`:

> ```
> export class Appointment {
>     $key: string;
>     name: string;
>     email: string
>     mobile: number;
>     car: string;
>     image1: string;
>     minPrice: number;
>     maxPrice: number;
>     currentPrice: number;
>     steps: number;
> }
> ```

`registration.service.ts`:

> ```
> import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
> import { Registration } from '../shared/Registration';
> import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireObject } from '@angular/fire/database';
>
> @Injectable({
>   providedIn: 'root'
> })
> export class RegistrationService {
>   bookingListRef: AngularFireList<any>;
>   bookingRef: AngularFireObject<any>;
>
>   constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }
>   
>   // Create
>   createBooking(apt: Registration) {
>     return this.bookingListRef.push({
>       name: apt.name,
>       mobile: apt.mobile,
>       email: apt.email,
>       confirmEmail: apt.confirmEmail
>     })
>   }
>
>   // Get Single
>   getBooking(id: string) {
>     this.bookingRef = this.db.object('/Registration/' + id);
>     return this.bookingRef;
>   }
>
>   // Get List
>   getBookingList() {
>     this.bookingListRef = this.db.list('/Registration');
>     return this.bookingListRef;
>   }
>
>   // Update
>   updateBooking(id, apt: Registration) {
>     return this.bookingRef.update({
>       name: apt.name,
>       mobile: apt.mobile,
>       email: apt.email,
>       confirmEmail: apt.confirmEmail
>     })
>   }
>
>   // Delete
>   deleteBooking(id: string) {
>     this.bookingRef = this.db.object('/Registration/' + id);
>     this.bookingRef.remove();
>   }
> }
> ```

`Registration.ts`:

> ```
> export class Registration {
>     $key: string;
>     name: string;
>     mobile: number;
>     email: string;
>     confirmEmail: string;
> }
> ```

When referencing these two services in my `make-appointment.page.ts` file, I have no issues when a user types in their inputs, but in my `registration.page.ts` file, as soon as the user submits their inputs, an error is given in the console, stating:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Why are my inputs recognized in my `Make-Appointment` page but not in my `Registration` page?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The only problem I could think of you just declared `bookingListRef` but not initialized with at least an empty array like `bookingListRef: AngularFireList<any> = []`. Unless you provide what you are doing in `make-appointment.page.ts` it's hard to guess the problem.

Comment: Thank you @Ravikumar! The issue was with the initialization. After using @Anders's method the Registration page now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ravikumar mentions, it seems like your bookingListRef isn't initialised.

It could be amended by retrieving the list when your services are constructed. Simply call `callBookingList()` in the constructor, eg.:

```js
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { 
    this.getBookingList()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the issue. I added this.getBookingList() to the constructor in my registration.service.ts, and now the user's inputs from the Registration page are being stored in Firebase.